# Where does this Greg Anderson quote come from?

Tags: quote-source

I see various people attribute the quote, "Focus on the journey, not the destination. Joy is found not in finishing an activity but in doing it" to Greg Anderson. However, I haven't been able to find where he actually *said* it. Does anybody know, or is it a misattribution? If so, who *actually* said it?

Answer (score 3):

This is from ***The 22 Non-Negotiable Laws of Wellness*** (1995):

> The Law of Mindfulness reminds us to focus on the journey, not the destination. Joy is found not in finishing an activity but in *doing* it. Become aware of all that is here now, and enjoy it. While this guideline may pose a real challenge to many type-A personalities, it’s the essence and power of the Law of Mindfulness.
>
> <sub>Greg Anderson (1995). *The 22 Non-Negotiable Laws of Wellness*, chapter 13. San Francisco: HarperCollins.</sub>

Of course, the idea in the quotation, that a journey may be more important than its destination, was not original to Anderson. This has been a commonplace for some time:

> ’Twas for the journey, not the goal, I cared.
>
> <sub>William Allingham (1883). [*Evil May-Day*, p. 80](https://archive.org/details/evilmaydayetc00alli/page/80/mode/2up). London: Longmans.</sub>

> The earth is a journey, not a goal; it is a place of trial, not the prize
>
> <sub>Geremia Bonomelli (1910). [*Christian Mysteries*, volume IV, p. 361](https://archive.org/details/christianmysteri04unknuoft/page/n363/mode/2up). Translated by Thomas Byrne. New York: Benziger.</sub>

> A book is the journey not the destination; it would be alive not dead.
>
> <sub>Giovanni Gentile (1922). [*The Theory of Mind As Pure Act*, p. xxvii](https://archive.org/details/theoryofmindaspu032443mbp/page/n29/mode/2up). London: Macmillan.</sub>

See also [Quote Investigator on “life is a journey, not a destination”](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/08/31/life-journey/) (2012), who notes a precursor in Emerson:

> To finish the moment, to find the journey’s end in every step of the road, to live the greatest number of good hours, is wisdom.
>
> <sub>Ralph Waldo Emerson (1844). [*Essays: Second Series*, p. 65](https://archive.org/details/essayssecondser01emergoog/page/n74/mode/2up). Boston: James Munroe.</sub>